# Move Keybindings from VSCode to PhpStorm

Tags: visual-studio-code, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide, vscode-keybinding

Is there any way to export your key-bindings from VSCode and import them to PhpStorm?

I know that there is an extension for PhpStorm but I have already customised my shortcuts in VSCode. So I would love to simply move it from one to another.

Comment: all the keybindings are in a text JSON file, write a script that changes it into a format that PHPStroms likes and in the process translate the used commands, if needed write extensions for PHPStorm that implements missing functionality. All in all a whole lot of work

Comment: Yes, there's no easy way of doing that.